# Standard Meaning/Purpose of Exposed Areas on a PCB?

Tags: pcb, standard

I noticed that on some circuits, there will be dots or rings of exposed circuit material.

Take for instance the back plate of a Nest thermostat:
https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/6J2elHPEJArWXaE6.huge

There is a thin ring around the inside, outside, and several dots of exposed brass colored PCB metal.

Is it a fair assumption that these always connect to ground? Or is this something that isn't standard?

Comment: never assume "always"

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Red arrow: these are targets used by optical sensors in the pick and place machine to detect and register the board so the machine knows exactly where the board is and can place components on it accurately.

Blue arrow: these are test points to probe various signals, either for automated testing of the board before or after assembly, or for manual testing/debugging during design/development or rework/repair.

Answer (score 0):

**WiFi antenna**?  Similar to [these](http://www.wa5vjb.com/products7.html) disc-shaped PC board "antennas" that have traces going 'round their edges.

But I think it's more likely to be **the place a shield touches the board**.  I've seen pictures of later versions of Nest thermostats ([here's the new Thermostat E](https://fccid.io/ZQAT40/Internal-Photos/Internal-Photos-3534856)) and much of the board is encased by shielding.

Did you take this photo or did you find it somewhere?  If the latter, maybe it's missing the shielding.